# 100vh results in scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

I have some really simple html/css that uses 100vh on a body tag, and 100% (or 100vh, I've tried both) on two inline block span's, each span of which has a width of 50vw. I expect to see both spans side by side, each taking up half the screen, and each as tall as the screen - no scrollbars, no white space. Body also has a margin of 0 to help with this. What I see is what I expected except that there is a small vertical scroll bar. I also removed all whitespace from inside the body, as I know this can add space beyond the 100% width. But I can't figure out why I get the scrollbar... I know I can just add an overflow: hidden to body and the scrollbar goes away, but again - why the scrollbar in the first place?

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }

    span {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #left {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body><span id="left"></span><span id="right"></span></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding the `vertical-align: top;` to `span` - https://jsfiddle.net/g3u9hckL/

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately that's the nature of inline elements.  You need to add `vertical-align:top` to force no line height and other font related spacing.

```css
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }

    span {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    #left {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<span id="left"></span><span id="right"></span>
```

Comment: My answer is better, it has `vertical-align: middle;`  But I am vote capped for today anyway ^^

Comment: @CodeiSir What? How exactly is `vertical-align: middle` better?

Comment: @JoshCrozier it's not, it's the same

Comment: OK I get it - the default is veritcal-align: baseline, so the tiny extra space is coming from the font descenders. Wild. So even veritical-align: bottom fixes this as well - anything except the default of vertical-align: baseline.

Comment: OK, maybe I don't get it! :) If I remove the vertical-align: top but add some content to the spans, then the scrollbar also goes away. It is only there if the spans are empty - I don't see how that is connected to vertical-align.

Comment: @user3399706 to be perfectly honest, neither do I.  I picked up throwing `vertical-align:top` on `inline-block` elements from when I had to style HTML emails.  I know it eliminates that line height, but I don't know why it's inconsistent with non-empty inline-block elements.

Answer (score 5):

That's because of the inline element white space margin.

Here I used the `margin-bottom: -4px;` hack (and there is many more) to remove it. Do note though, when using this hack you need to check it against the current font size and adjust it accordingly.

*If you really need inline-block, use the `vertical-align` hack*

A better way is to either use `flex` or `float` (to support older browsers).

Here is `margin-bottom: -4px;`

```css
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }

    span {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: -4px;
    }

    #left {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
  <span id="left"></span><span id="right"></span>
```

Here is `flex`

```css
body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    span {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
    }

    #left {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<span id="left"></span><span id="right"></span>
```

Here is `float`

```css
body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }

    span {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    #left {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<span id="left"></span><span id="right"></span>
```

Comment: @LGSon `margin-bottom: -4px;` isn't a proper solution if you increase the `font-size` then it doesn't work - https://jsfiddle.net/torbd8g0/

Comment: @Anonymous That's correct, and that's why I suggested float or flex.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "inline white space margin". If the spans in my example are empty, you get the extra white space and a small scrollbar. If I put any content into the spans, this goes away and the page shows as intended. There is no way that having content takes *less* space than not having content.

Comment: @user3399706 It does, check these 2 fiddle demos and you'll see ... https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/822bs63m/ ... https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/822bs63m/1/

Comment: Sure, I can avoid this issue a number of ways - changing to floats, using position: absolute instead, etc. I'm trying to determine if what I'm seeing is a browser issue, which I believe it is (see my previous comment). Interestingly, all browsers I've tried do exactly the same thing, which seems to invalidate my contention that this is a browser issue. Still - adding content to  the empty spans also makes the scrollbar go away, and that just does not make sense to me. :)

Comment: @TwinFeats Its not the content itself, by lining up span's on same line is yet another way to get rid of the white space margin, which kicks in as soon as you add content to them. ... as those fiddles shows

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the white space under the span elements by adding `vertical-align: middle;` to them: I learned that today and it's very simple

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    span {
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle; /* here */
    }
    #left {
      background-color: red;
    }
    #right {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body><span id="left"></span><span id="right"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style for "body".

```
body
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I didn't have to make any other changes to the original CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp